# How to deal with this coarse mesh for sculping after boolean operation

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I forgot to sufficiently refine the mesh on the boolean cylinder to be used on the target geometry. The target geometry now looks like as attached. I tried a general remesh but I lose all my sculpting detail. Are there other tips?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the (default) *Draw* brush, enable *Dyntopo* (choose the *Detail Size* you want), put the *Strength* at 0, and sculpt this part, it won't create any bump but it will triangulate.

Comment: Thats a nice tip. I had to use "front faces only"  to ensure only this side is affected. thanks!